# Change value of the next element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three text fields per row in my table.

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" data-type="number" name="qty[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" data-type="number" name="ucost[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" data-type="number" name="total[]" readonly /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" data-type="number" name="qty[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" data-type="number" name="ucost[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" data-type="number" name="total[]" readonly /></td>
</tr>
```

The value of the text field named `total[]` per row must be (`qty * ucost`).
If the user input value to the `qty` field, the corresponding total field must be changed.

How to do it using the name attribute?
I tried this code,

```
$(document).on('keyup', "input[name='qty[]']", function(e) {
    if (e.which >= 37 && e.which <= 40) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    $("input[name='total[]']").val() = ($("input[name='ucost[]']").val() * $("input[name=qty[]']").val());
});
```

But it is not working.

Comment: not sure if its a typo or not but `epreventDefault()` will error if your code goes down that path and attempts to call it. `e.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `val()` method incorrectly. You can use `closest()` and `find()` methods like following.

```
$(document).on('keyup', "input[name='qty[]'], input[name='ucost[]']", function(e) {
  if (e.which >= 37 && e.which <= 40) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  var qty = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="qty[]"]').val();
  var cost = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="ucost[]"]').val();
  var total = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="total[]"]');

  total.val(qty * cost);
});
```

```js
$(document).on('keyup', "input[name='qty[]'], input[name='ucost[]']", function(e) {
  if (e.which >= 37 && e.which <= 40) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  var qty = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="qty[]"]').val();
  var cost = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="ucost[]"]').val();
  var total = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="total[]"]');

  total.val(qty * cost);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" data-type="number" name="qty[]" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" data-type="number" name="ucost[]" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" data-type="number" name="total[]" readonly />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" data-type="number" name="qty[]" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" data-type="number" name="ucost[]" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" data-type="number" name="total[]" readonly />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How about triggering that function if the ucost field is changed? 
Can I bind that eventlistener to 2 textfields?

Comment: I've bind the eventlistener to both textfields. @DjGenexxe

Answer (score 0):

It would be much better if you add common classes e.g. `total-fields`, `quantity-fields` etc. and then bind those events using classes.

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="quantity-fields" data-type="number" name="qty[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="cost-fields" data-type="number" name="ucost[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="total-fields" data-type="number" name="total[]" readonly /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="quantity-fields" data-type="number" name="qty[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="cost-fields" data-type="number" name="ucost[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="total-fields" data-type="number" name="total[]" readonly /></td>
</tr>


$(document).on('change', ".total-fields, .quantity-fields", function(e){
  var quantity = parseFloat( $(this).parent().find('.quantity-fields').val() );
  var cost = parseFloat( $(this).parent().find('.cost-fields').val() );
  var total = cost * quantity;
  $(this).parent().find('.total-fields').val( total );
});//change
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue is `.val()` takes a value as a input to set a value not assigns one. And you can check each name attribute against what it starts with like this:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oss16La2/4/

```
$(document).on('keyup', "input[name^=qty], input[name^=ucost]", function(e) {
    if (e.which >= 37 && e.which <= 40) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    // Find only fields in same row
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var ucost = parseInt(row.find("input[name^=ucost]").val());
    var qty = parseInt(row.find("input[name^=qty]").val());

    // Check that both fields have a valid numerical value
    if (isNaN(ucost) || isNaN(qty)) {
        return;
    }

    // Calc product and update field in the same row
    var product = ucost * qty;
    row.find("input[name^=total]").val(product);
});
```

EDIT: Update to handle both fields, not having a value in a field and only updating fields in same row. The way you are selecting fields will select all the fields. You want to make sure you are only dealing with fields in the same row.

Comment: You need to use `parseInt()` on input values before multiplying.

Comment: Oops just copied and pasted. Odd though the previous fiddle was showing correct values even without the parseInt but better save than sorry!

Comment: No need to use `parseInt()` when multiplying. It converts string to number automatically. @Mike